# Jtable en Java problemas al actualizar fila

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy teniendo problemas al actualizar la cantidad de un producto en un Jtable en Java.

Tengo una vista donde el usuario agregar productos a una lista de compra, en la cual se supone que al momento de ingresar un producto que no se encuentra en la lista lo tiene que insertar en una nueva fila del Jtable, pero si ya ha sido agregado el producto anteriormente solo se debe actualizar la cantidad, el sistema ya actualiza la cantidad si es que ya el producto fue añadido anteriormente pero me esta insertando nuevas filas ya intente poner un else para que si el producto no se encuentra inserte una fila nueva el nuevo producto pero si ya se encuentra solo aumente la cantidad anteriormás la nueva cantidad seleccionada del el producto, este es el código que hace la función que menciono:

```
idProducto = this.producto.getP_id();
            producto = this.producto.getP_nombre();
            precio = this.producto.getP_precio();
            cantidad = (int) ventForm.cantidadProductoJDialog.getValue();
            stock = this.producto.getP_stock();
            supTotal = cantidad * precio;

            ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
            lista.add(item);
            lista.add(idProducto);
            lista.add(producto);
            lista.add(cantidad);
            lista.add(precio);
            lista.add(supTotal);

            int index;
            index = lista.indexOf(idProducto);

            if (index != -1) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El idice " + index);
                for (int i = 0; i < ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.getRowCount(); i++) {

                    if (ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.getValueAt(i, 1).equals(idProducto)) {
                        int nuevaCantidad = Integer.parseInt(ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.getValueAt(i, 3).toString()) + cantidad;
                        double nuevoSuptotal = nuevaCantidad * precio;
                        ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.setValueAt(nuevaCantidad, i, 3);
                        ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.setValueAt(nuevoSuptotal, i, 5);

                    }

                }

            }

            Object[] listaArticulos = new Object[6];
            listaArticulos[0] = lista.get(0);
            listaArticulos[1] = lista.get(1);
            listaArticulos[2] = lista.get(2);
            listaArticulos[3] = lista.get(3);
            listaArticulos[4] = lista.get(4);
            listaArticulos[5] = lista.get(5);

            modelo.addRow(listaArticulos);

            ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.setModel(modelo);
```

Nota: ya intente meter en un else la parte donde se insertan los datos en Jtable (la parte del arreglo `Object[]`) realice esta otra manera pero no agrega nada:

```
`if (index != -1) {
                    // si esta solo actualiza la fila en la columna de canditad
                        
                    for (int i = 0; i < ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.getRowCount(); i++) {

                        if (ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.getValueAt(i, 1).equals(idProducto)) {
                            int nuevaCantidad = Integer.parseInt(ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.getValueAt(i, 3).toString()) + cantidad;
                            double nuevoSuptotal = nuevaCantidad * precio;
                            ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.setValueAt(nuevaCantidad, i, 3);
                            ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.setValueAt(nuevoSuptotal, i, 5);

                        }

                    }
                }else{
                    // si No esta ingresa una nueva fila
                       Object[] listaArticulos = new Object[6];
                listaArticulos[0] = lista.get(0);
                listaArticulos[1] = lista.get(1);
                listaArticulos[2] = lista.get(2);
                listaArticulos[3] = lista.get(3);
                listaArticulos[4] = lista.get(4);
                listaArticulos[5] = lista.get(5);

                modelo.addRow(listaArticulos);

                ventForm.tablaDetalleVentas.setModel(modelo);
                }`
```

Dejo la imagen del resultado que estoy obteniendo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo espero puedan orientarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que es porque se llena la lista `lista` antes del condicional; los cambios que hice (*conservando al máximo la estructura y forma como planteas tu codigo*) fueron estos:

- Declarar `lista` con un ámbito global.
- Llenar `lista` dentro de la clausula `else`
- Poner un indice algo 'dinamico' (también global) para el array `lista`

  ```
  else {
    lista.add(item);
    lista.add(idProducto);
    lista.add(producto);
    lista.add(cantidad);
    lista.add(precio);
    lista.add(supTotal);

    Object[] listaArticulos = new Object[6];
             listaArticulos[0] = lista.get(k);
             listaArticulos[1] = lista.get(k+1);
             listaArticulos[2] = lista.get(k+2);
             listaArticulos[3] = lista.get(k+3);
             listaArticulos[4] = lista.get(k+4);
             listaArticulos[5] = lista.get(k+5);

    k+=myTable.getModel().getColumnCount();

    modelo.addRow(listaArticulos);
  }
  ```

Los datos de prueba ingresados exactamente en este orden:

```
//ID, Nombre, Precio, Stock (?), Cantidad
newTestProduct("AR1","Ariel",27.5,"1",1);
newTestProduct("ZE3","Jabon zets",13.0,"1",1);
newTestProduct("CD9","Crema Dental",10.0,"1",3);
newTestProduct("AR1","Ariel",27.5,"1",1);
newTestProduct("AB7","Ajax Blanch",12.7,"1",1);
newTestProduct("CD9","Crema Dental",10.0,"1",1);
```

Aparecen reflejadas las actualizaciones de productos existentes anteriormente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, eso resolvió el problema agradezco saludos